# group and sum by a custom data range

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I'd like to group the column `amount` by a custom weekly date range, being every monday to sunday.

My data looks like this

```
date              weekday         amount
---------------|--------------|---------------
2015-03-01        sun              40
2015-03-02        mon              670
2015-03-03        tue              430
2015-03-04        wed              70
2015-03-05        thu              220
2015-03-06        fri              7
2015-03-07        sat              780
2015-03-08        sun              43
2015-03-09        mon              10
2015-03-10        tue              200
2015-03-11        wed              30
2015-03-12        thu              40
2015-03-13        fri              500
2015-03-14        sat              80
2015-03-15        sun              20
2015-03-16        mon              30
2015-03-17        tue              90
2015-03-18        wed              50
2015-03-19        thu              50
2015-03-20        fri              60
2015-03-21        sat              810
2015-03-22        sun              30
2015-03-23        mon              50
```

etc,

etc,

and I would like to achieve something like this

```
amount         week
-----------|--------------------------------|---
2200        2015-03-02 - 2015-03-08
910         2015-03-09 - 2015-03-15
1120        2015-03-16 - 2015-03-22
```

or, if possible this would be better (if not then I'll just regex the above example into new columns)

```
amount         date_start         date_end
-----------|------------------|----------------|---
2200           2015-03-02         2015-03-08
910            2015-03-09         2015-03-15
1120           2015-03-16         2015-03-22
```

Comment: is this going to be run from an application or just straight up sql?

Comment: You don't actually store the weekday, do you?

Comment: it's running on mysql. nope, i don't store the weekday, that was just to illustrate my need to group by custom week day/range

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here @user3768071 this works for your first week, challenge is to get it to work for all weeks http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1742b/9, I have to go catch my train so no more time

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the desired result be as follows? If not, why not...

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | amount |
+------------+--------+
| 2015-03-01 |     40 |40
+------------+--------+
| 2015-03-02 |    670 |
| 2015-03-03 |    430 |
| 2015-03-04 |     70 |
| 2015-03-05 |    220 |
| 2015-03-06 |      7 |
| 2015-03-07 |    780 |
| 2015-03-08 |     43 |2220
+------------+--------+
| 2015-03-09 |     10 |
| 2015-03-10 |    200 |
| 2015-03-11 |     30 |
| 2015-03-12 |     40 |
| 2015-03-13 |    500 |
| 2015-03-14 |     80 |
| 2015-03-15 |     20 |880
+------------+--------+
| 2015-03-16 |     30 |
| 2015-03-17 |     90 |
| 2015-03-18 |     50 |
| 2015-03-19 |     50 |
| 2015-03-20 |     60 |
| 2015-03-21 |    810 |
| 2015-03-22 |     30 |1120
+------------+--------+
| 2015-03-23 |     50 |50
+------------+--------+
```

Assuming I'm right, then:

```
SELECT MIN(date) start
     , MAX(date) end
     , SUM(amount) total 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY YEARWEEK(date,1);
+------------+------------+-------+
| start      | end        | total |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2015-03-01 | 2015-03-01 |    40 |
| 2015-03-02 | 2015-03-08 |  2220 |
| 2015-03-09 | 2015-03-15 |   880 |
| 2015-03-16 | 2015-03-22 |  1120 |
| 2015-03-23 | 2015-03-23 |    50 |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: In that case you need to use whatever arithmetical logic pervades in your universe.

Comment: sort of worked, well works if i include this... WHERE date > '2015-03-02' ...but really my dates go from 2014 jan to 2015 current date, and without the where clause the dates get screwed up like for example, 2014-01-01 - 2015-01-04, 2014-01-06 - 2015-01-11, etc.

Comment: sorry strawberry, not sure if i posted before you answered or vice versa. this site is weird when refreshing for replies. where you said.... Assuming I'm right, then: ...
 
sort of worked, well works if i include this... WHERE date > '2015-03-02' ...but really my dates go from 2014 jan to 2015 current date, and without the where clause the dates get screwed up like for example, 2014-01-01 - 2015-01-04, 2014-01-06 - 2015-01-11, etc.

Comment: See edit above. But note that YEARWEEK behaves a little differently from WEEK, so you may need to adjust this slightly.

Comment: lovely juvely! impressed and appreciate your help. cheers strawberry!

Comment: Maybe edit your question to show correct arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:-

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, CONCAT(date, ' - ', date + INTERVAL 6 DAY) AS week 
FROM Your_Table 
GROUP BY WEEK(date, 1) 
ORDER BY WEEK(date, 1)
```

Comment: already tried this but seems to group by a default week, no provision in there to specify my custom week from mon to sun

Comment: lovely juvely! impressed and appreciate your help. cheers strawberry!